# Hide Custom TabBarController using Three20 SDK in photo gallery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

I created a custom tabbar which is a subclass of `UITabbarController`. There is an `UIImageView`, nsarray and five `UIButton` in my tabbar. I set each button with different images, then set the array with the buttons.

In the appDelegate .m file i created instances of 5 different class and their navigation controllers. Set the `UITabbarController's` viewcontrollers with the array of instances.

Everything is fine and works well. I used Three20 sdk for the photo gallery. Using     
`self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`

code row, hides the original tabbar of ios sdk, but I could not hide my custom tabbar when the photo will be displayed.

Any suggesstion will be appreciated.

---

My system works like that : In mainViewController class there is 10 gallery pictures. When i click one of them app goes to PhotoTest2Controller class and the clicked gallery pictures are listed. When i click a photo, it displays bigger.

i did a few changes on my class which is a subclass of TTThumbsViewController, named PhotoTest2Controller.

But the tabbar is visible when i open the gallery and photos. In PhotoTest2Controller class, i did the below changes in viewDidAppear.

```
TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
```

`navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;`
`navigator.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:TTScreenBounds()] autorelease];`

```
TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"tt://order?waitress=(initWithWaitress:)" toModalViewController:[PhotoTest2Controller class]];
```

what can i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push a single controller without the tab bar controller, you can push it as a model view

```
// The ordering controller will appear as a modal view controller, animated from bottom     to top
[map from:@"tt://portal/test"
   toModalViewController:[ContentController class]];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how can i use this code snippet ? i dont know anything about map.

Comment: Are u using three20's TTNavigator in your app delegate? if not, you can present the controller using the standard controller function:   [self presentModalViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>

Comment: i dont use TTNavigator in app delegate aporat.

Comment: aporat i realized now, i try something like that in my class which is a subclass of TTThumbsViewController. [self presentModalViewController:PhotoTest2Controller animated:YES]; but it gives error: expected expression before 'PhotoTest2Controller'

Comment: aporat i tried something related to your code snippet in viewDidAppear method [self presentModalViewController:self animated:YES]; when i ran the app like this, navigation bar and images will lost.

Comment: i found a solution and it worked. What i did is creating a method in app delegate file which hides the custom tabbar by setting the frame to be under the screen then calling it in the gallery file.